# How to deal with large number of references in one \cite{}

Tags: citing, natbib, sourcecode

I am writing a review type document and very often I have to cite 5+ papers in a single `\cite{}` command. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to best deal with this. The problem is demonstrated below:

```
This sentence needs a lot of references\cite{paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4,paper5,paper6,paper....}.
```

I don't like to have lines go past 80 char so I really want a way to do this that is more "narrow". Where ever possible I will move the word that the list of references should be after to its own line, but very rarely does this help completely. I have tried doing this:

```
... references\cite{paper12,paper13,paper14}
~\cite{paper15,paper16}
```

But this leads to a break in the range if the papers are all consecutive:

[image: Should be 12-16]

I have also tried escaping the new line:

```
...references\cite{paper12,paper13,paper14,\
paper15,paper16}
```

But that wont build.

How can I split up my `\cite{}`'s so that I don't have extreemly long lines all over the place?

I am using nat-bib by way of `\usepackage{rsc}` and the bibliography styles from that package are a requirement.

Comment: Doesn't a simple line break after the comma work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

1. TeX treats a single linebreak as a space and
2. inter-element spaces in a list of citation key names are not significant,

no special escaping of the linebreak is required. Any of the following strategies will yield identical output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 80-CHAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
This sentence needs a lot of references\cite{bertram,doody,aksin,angenendt,gillies,glashow,herrmann}.

This sentence needs a lot of references\cite{bertram, doody, aksin, angenendt, gillies, glashow, herrmann}.

This sentence needs a lot of references\cite{bertram,doody,aksin,angenendt,%
gillies,glashow,herrmann}.

This sentence needs a lot of references\cite{bertram,doody,aksin,angenendt,
gillies,glashow,herrmann}.

This sentence needs a lot of references%
\cite{bertram,doody,aksin,angenendt,gillies,glashow,herrmann}.

This sentence needs a lot of references%
\cite{bertram, doody, aksin, angenendt, gillies, glashow, herrmann}.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 80-CHAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first two cases have input lines over 80 characters in length, comparing no spaces between keys and spaces between keys. The other cases show several possible ways to shorten the input lines.

For the example, I used a sample `.bib` file that should be on your system if you have the package `biblatex` installed.